# UITextField can't become first responder in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, uitextfield, becomefirstresponder

## Context

Basic list. When user press '+', code creates a new item with default text that user can change.
[image: UI]

## Problem

I want to focus the new item as soon as user press '+' so that user can type desired name. I try to achieve this with this code:

```
func focus() {
        title.becomeFirstResponder()
        title.selectAll(nil)
    }
```

But `becomeFirstResponder()` always returns `false`.

**How can I give focus to `UITextField` in my `UITableviewCell` after creation ?**

---

Here is full code of `UITableViewController` for reference:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController{
    var model: [String] = ["Existing item"]
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return model.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemUI", for: indexPath) as! ItemUI
        cell.update(with: model[indexPath.item])
        return cell
    }
    
    @IBAction func createItem(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: model.count, section: 0)
        model.append("new item")
        tableView.reloadData()
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
        
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
            let cell = self.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath) as! ItemUI
            cell.focus()
        }
    }
}

class ItemUI: UITableViewCell{
    @IBOutlet var title: UITextField!
    
    func update(with: String) {
        title.text = with
    }
    
    func focus() {
        title.becomeFirstResponder()
        title.selectAll(nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ok I found the problem!**

I was using method `self.tableView(self.tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)` instead of `self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)`.

Here is what the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614861-tableview) has to say:
"Never call this method yourself. If you want to retrieve cells from your table, call the table view's `cellForRow(at:)` method instead."

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean in your view controller to keep track of adding item i.e  *isAddingItem* with default value false and when you add new item simply update *isAddingItem* to true. In tableview *cellForRowAt* method check for last cell of tableview and if *isAddingItem* is true then selected all text of textfield and make it first responder.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemUI", for: indexPath) as! ItemUI
        cell.update(with: model[indexPath.item])

        if isAddingItem && indexPath.item == model.count {
            // make your textfield first here and select text here
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Also check if you have set textfield delegate.

Comment: Is a good answer, you might need to add a condition to check if the last element still has the default text value, if not then leave it out of focus.

Comment: Thanks Azhar for your answer, but I found the real issue, check my answer